# animate image once using SwiftGifOrigin swift4

Tags: ios, swift, animated-gif, tgifimage

I am trying to animate once using **SwiftGifOrigin** pod but it does not work, using `.loadgif` the image can animate unlimited times but I want to animate image once

image outlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var gifimage: UIImageView!
```

using this method image animate unlimited times

```
gifimage.loadGif(name: "1_splash1")
```

and using this method nothing happened it does not show any image

```
let animated_image =   UIImage.gif(name: "1_splash1")
        gifimage.animationImages = animated_image?.images
        gifimage.animationDuration   = (animated_image?.duration)!
        gifimage.animationRepeatCount = 1
        gifimage.startAnimating()
```

Comment: check this https://github.com/swiftgif/SwiftGif/wiki/Extended-use

Comment: I tried your code, and its working fine(simulator), since i didn't have your "1_splash1" image, i used the one with the library. the image stops after the first animation.

Comment: Please try to increase the animation duration, for example try to give gifimage.animationDuration   = 5.0

Comment: IOS i check already

Comment: Vinaykrishnan but its not working on my iphone

Comment: Vinaykrishnan just increase the duration of image but nothing happen

Comment: its working fine in SwiftyGif may be the problem is in the pod thank u